# Can the command "chcp 65001" work in Windows 7?

Tags: command-line, utf-8, windows-7, codepages

Because of the language, I want to use `chcp 65001` to let the command window become English, and call `systeminfo` to get data.

However, using Windows 7 after using `chcp 65001` the program `systeminfo` can't find anything but instead shows the error:

> OS Name: A device attached to the system is not functioning

Is `chcp 65001` not supported on Windows 7?

Comment: `chcp` doesn't change the language. So if your Windows is not an English Windows, it's not going to be magically showing messages in English just because you change the codepage - which only controls how characters are _encoded_ when displayed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the comment. My computer is windows 10 and the language is traditional Chinese, and when I use `chcp 65001` it will become English. Even if the language doesn't be changed, the content should come out ?

Comment: Also, the error comes 'A device attached to the system is not functioning'

Comment: This question belongs on [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: @KenWhite OK, thanks for information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes: `chcp.com` exists in Windows 7. On both x32 and x64.
- Yes: it supports `65001` as parameter to set UTF-8 as codepage.

However, this will rarily help you, as many things are not supported with this codepage in a console. See [How to use unicode characters in Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843552/4299358)